# Why super here in class A not calling the object class as super method is meant to call the parent class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class A:
    def method(self):
        print('a is running')
        super().method()

class B:
    def method(self):
        print('b is running')
        super().method()

class C:
    def method(self):
        print('c is running')
        
class X(A,B):
    def method(self):
        print('x is running')
        super().method()  

class Y(B,C):
    pass

class P(X,Y,C):
    def method(self):
        print('p is running')
        super().method()
print(P.mro())
g=P()
g.method()
```

Question 1 :I understand the output from the MRO point of view but my question is since super is supposed to call the parent class so why `class A` is not calling the object class here?

Question 2 : If I write `super().method()` in class C it gives me an error but instead of giving error shouldn't it search in the object class for `method()` and since there is no `method()` present in the object class, the search should stop there?

Question 3 : If I use '`super().__init__()`' in `class C`, it doesn't give me any errors but why?

Comment: " since super is supposed to call the parent class " no, it's supposed to call **the next method in the method resolution order**

Comment: The `super().method()` in class A is not calling object.  It is calling the next class in the MRO, which is `B` in this case.  For `C`, there is no "next class", so it calls `object.method`, which fails.

Comment: "but instead of giving error shouldn't it search in the object class for method() and since there is no method() present in the object class, the search should stop there?" the search stops and since no `method` attribute is found in any of the classes in the method resolution order, then an `AttributeError` should be raised... why would you expect it to just silently fail? That would be very surprising

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga but when I use super().__init__() in class C it doesn't give any errors, does that mean that object class has an __init__ method?

Comment: @madhur `object.__init__` exists, you can check, `print(object.__init__)`